# DataGridView allow edit only clicking F2

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, .net-4.0

I wish edit my `DataGridView` only clicking `F2` and not with doubleclick on the cell...

googling I've found the property:

```
dgv.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnF2;
```

that works the editing with `F2`, but also with the doubleclick...
is there a way to avoid the doubleclick editing?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the [`EditMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editmode(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically` and then handle [`KeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) event:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F2)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
    }
}
```